# python - 3 Turing Machine script, getting errors on an undefined variable, even though I assigned it

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, ide, turing-machines

I'm working on a Turing machine in python and i'm getting an error for an undefined variable even though I have assigned it. Any help?

the exact error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 71, in <module>
    read()
  File "main.py", line 20, in read
    if state == 0:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'state' referenced before assignment
```

my code is:

```
#Turing Machine In Python
#by adrian wheeler

#the script

index = 5
state = 0
tape = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]




def MoveRight():
    index += 1

def MoveLeft():
    index -= 1

def read():
    if state == 0:
        if tape[index] == 0:
            tape.insert(index, "1")
            state = 2
            MoveRight()
            read()
    
    if state == 2:
        if tape[index] == 0:
            tape.insert(index, "1")
            state = 3
            MoveRight
            read()
    
    if state == 3:
        if tape[index] == 0:
            tape.insert(index, "1")
            state = 4
            MoveLeft()
            read()
            
    if state == 4:
        if tape[index] == 1:
            tape.insert(index, "0")
            state = 4
            MoveLeft
            read()
            
    if state == 4:
        if tape[index] == 0:
            tape.insert(index, "0")
            state = 5
            MoveRight()
            read()
            
    if state == 5:
        if tape[index] == 0:
            tape.insert(index, "0")
            state = 5
            MoveRight()
            read()
            
    if state == 5:
        if tape[index] == 1:
            tape.insert(index, "1")
            state = 0
            MoveRight()
            read()
    
#running the script

read()
```

I'm very sure I defined the variable before using it.

I've tried moving it around to different spots, and searched up a fix on google, I still can't seem to find the fix. I am using an IDE as i'm at school, maybe that's the problem, please help?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Declare `state`, `index` and `tape` as local variables at the top of your functions**

Every function is a new [namespace](https://realpython.com/python-namespaces-scope/). This means that even though the variable `state` was defined in the outer [scope](https://realpython.com/python-namespaces-scope/), it is not defined in the function. To fix this we can use python's [`global` keyword](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-keyword-in-python/), to ensure that your variables are defined within the function.

**Quick explanation of `global` keyword:**

Surprisingly, this code contains an error:

```
foo = 1

def do_something():
    foo = 2 # Uh, oh... foo is undefined
```

Let's fix it:

```
foo = 1

def do_something():
    global foo # make sure foo is global
    foo = 2 # This works fine!
```

So, back to your code: We need to put global key words at the top of all your functions as in:

```
#Turing Machine In Python
#by adrian wheeler

#the script

index = 5
state = 0
tape = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]




def MoveRight():
    global index # Make sure our vars are global!
    index += 1

def MoveLeft():
    global index # Make sure our vars are global!
    index -= 1

def read():
    global state, index, tape # Make sure our vars are global!
    if state == 0:
        if tape[index] == 0:
            tape.insert(index, "1")
            state = 2
            MoveRight()
            read()
    
    if state == 2:
        if tape[index] == 0:
            tape.insert(index, "1")
            state = 3
            MoveRight
            read()
    
    if state == 3:
        if tape[index] == 0:
            tape.insert(index, "1")
            state = 4
            MoveLeft()
            read()
            
    if state == 4:
        if tape[index] == 1:
            tape.insert(index, "0")
            state = 4
            MoveLeft
            read()
            
    if state == 4:
        if tape[index] == 0:
            tape.insert(index, "0")
            state = 5
            MoveRight()
            read()
            
    if state == 5:
        if tape[index] == 0:
            tape.insert(index, "0")
            state = 5
            MoveRight()
            read()
            
    if state == 5:
        if tape[index] == 1:
            tape.insert(index, "1")
            state = 0
            MoveRight()
            read()
    
#running the script

read()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that by default functions can't access variables that are defined outside them.

There are 2 ways to solve this.

The first is to just declare that you are referencing the global variable state by typing `global state` at the beginning of the function. This will tell the program to use the global state variable instead of trying to access a variable that for as it knows, does not exist.

```
def MoveRight():
    global index
    index += 1

def MoveLeft():
    global index
    index -= 1

def read():

    global state
    global tape
    global index

    if state == 0:
        if tape[index] == 0:
            tape.insert(index, "1")
            state = 2
            MoveRight()
            read()
    
    if state == 2:
        if tape[index] == 0:
            tape.insert(index, "1")
            state = 3
            MoveRight()
            read()
    
    if state == 3:
        if tape[index] == 0:
            tape.insert(index, "1")
            state = 4
            MoveLeft()
            read()
            
    if state == 4:
        if tape[index] == 1:
            tape.insert(index, "0")
            state = 4
            MoveLeft
            read()
            
    if state == 4:
        if tape[index] == 0:
            tape.insert(index, "0")
            state = 5
            MoveRight()
            read()
            
    if state == 5:
        if tape[index] == 0:
            tape.insert(index, "0")
            state = 5
            MoveRight()
            read()
            
    if state == 5:
        if tape[index] == 1:
            tape.insert(index, "1")
            state = 0
            MoveRight()
            read()
```

Although the first method works, the preferred way is to pass the state as an argument into the function. The good part about this is that it is being made a copy, so if it's edited it won't change it on a global scale.

```
def MoveRight(index):
    index += 1

def MoveLeft(index):
    index -= 1

def read(state, tape, index):

    if state == 0:
        if tape[index] == 0:
            tape.insert(index, "1")
            state = 2
            MoveRight(index)
            read(state, tape, index)
    
    if state == 2:
        if tape[index] == 0:
            tape.insert(index, "1")
            state = 3
            MoveRight(index)
            read(state, tape, index)
    
    if state == 3:
        if tape[index] == 0:
            tape.insert(index, "1")
            state = 4
            MoveLeft(index)
            read(state, tape, index)
            
    if state == 4:
        if tape[index] == 1:
            tape.insert(index, "0")
            state = 4
            MoveLeft(index)
            read(state, tape, index)
            
    if state == 4:
        if tape[index] == 0:
            tape.insert(index, "0")
            state = 5
            MoveRight(index)
            read(state, tape, index)
            
    if state == 5:
        if tape[index] == 0:
            tape.insert(index, "0")
            state = 5
            MoveRight(index)
            read(state, tape, index)
            
    if state == 5:
        if tape[index] == 1:
            tape.insert(index, "1")
            state = 0
            MoveRight(index)
            read(state, tape, index)

read(state, tape, index)
```